# For-loop and Augmented Dickey-Fuller unit root test (ADF test)

Tags: r, for-loop

I am modelling with data set uschange from fpp2 package and I want to perform Augmented Dickey-Fuller unit root test (ADF test) with vars package. In this example I have five series with names "Consumption"  "Income" ,  "Production",  "Savings" and  "Unemployment". So my intention is to do ADF-test and put results in one object of class list. You can see code below:

```
#CODE
library(fpp2)
library(vars)

#Data
MY_DATA<-data.frame(uschange)
COL_NAMES<- names(MY_DATA)

#LOOP ADF
MY_LIST<-for(i in 1:ncol(MY_DATA)){

  summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "drift",selectlags = c("BIC")))
  summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "trend",selectlags = c("BIC")))
  summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "none",selectlags = c("BIC")))
}
```

But obviously I made some mistake and my code with loop is not working. So can anybody help how to fix this code in order to get results from ADF test from all five series in one object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from summary is just some text, in any case, you didn't assign these results anywhere

```
MY_LIST=vector("list",ncol(MY_DATA))
for(i in 1:ncol(MY_DATA)){
  MY_LIST[[i]]=list(
    summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "drift",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
    summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "trend",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
    summary(ur.df(MY_DATA[i], type = "none",selectlags = c("BIC")))
  )
}
```

or better yet

```
MY_LIST=apply(MY_DATA,2,function(x){
  return(
    list(
      summary(ur.df(x, type = "drift",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
      summary(ur.df(x, type = "trend",selectlags = c("BIC"))),
      summary(ur.df(x, type = "none",selectlags = c("BIC")))
    )
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Second code is works, but in first have some error.